# Pass ViewBag to PartialView from action controller that returns that PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an action controller that returns a partial view with a query. In this controller I have a viewbag with another query that I want to pass to the partial view so I can use it in a foreach.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult GetQuizResults(string ProfileResult, short occupationID)

        var query = from o in db.Occupations
                    where o.Profile.Equals(ProfileResult, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
                    select new QuestionnaireViewModel
                    {
                        OccupationID = o.OccupationID,
                        OccupationName = o.OccupationName,
                        OccupationDescription = o.OccupationDescription
                    };

        QuestionnaireViewModel occDetails = new QuestionnaireViewModel();
        ViewBag.OccDetails = occDetails.GetOccupationDetails(occupationID);

        return PartialView("_QuizResults", query.ToList());
    }
```

How can I pass ViewBag.OccDetails to the _QuizResults partial view?

In my partial view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<Proj.Models.QuestionnaireViewModel>

            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.OccDetails)
            {
                @item.OccupationDescriptionOc

            }
```

But I get the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to send ViewBag, everything is already done for you just use this way...

**For example:**

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<OccupationDetails>)ViewBag.OccDetails)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your _QuizResults partial view look like? You should be able to access it directly in the view using:

```
@ViewBag.OccDetails
```

Comment: Is your occDetails.GetOccupationDetails(occupationID) statement returning null?